# Need help to implement Flutter in app upgrade

Tags: flutter

Can anyone help me understand and implement flutter [in_app_update](https://pub.dev/packages/in_app_update) efficiently using "upgrader"(preferable) or any alternate methods.

Despite my multiple search over internet, I found just few articles related to that and I am sorry but unable to understand the official documents.

Any help would be appreciated greatly.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To explain it simply, the package provides you a method to check if an app has an update available: `InAppUpdate.checkForUpdate()`

This method will return an [AppUpdateInfo](https://pub.dev/documentation/in_app_update/latest/in_app_update/InAppUpdate-class.html) object contains infos such as `availableVersionCode` or `updateAvailability`.

You can then use these infos to prompt a dialog to remind the user to update the app, or force them to stop using the old app version.

Another method this package provides is `performImmediateUpdate`, which performs an update of the app.

You can check other methods provided [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/in_app_update/latest/in_app_update/InAppUpdate-class.html)

Sample project:

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:in_app_update/in_app_update.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  AppUpdateInfo? _updateInfo;
  GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey();

  // Platform messages are asynchronous, so we initialize in an async method.
  Future<void> checkForUpdate() async {
    InAppUpdate.checkForUpdate().then((info) {
      setState(() {
        _updateInfo = info;
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      showSnack(e.toString());
    });
  }

  void showSnack(String text) {
    if (_scaffoldKey.currentContext != null) {
      ScaffoldMessenger.of(_scaffoldKey.currentContext!)
          .showSnackBar(SnackBar(content: Text(text)));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        key: _scaffoldKey,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Sample App'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Center(
                child: Text('Update info: $_updateInfo'),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Check for Update'),
                onPressed: () => checkForUpdate(),
              ),
              ElevatedButton(
                child: Text('Perform immediate update'),
                onPressed: _updateInfo?.updateAvailability ==
                        UpdateAvailability.updateAvailable
                    ? () {
                        InAppUpdate.performImmediateUpdate()
                            .catchError((e) => showSnack(e.toString()));
                      }
                    : null,
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for effort which helped me to understand / implement this now, I just needed guidance at some point where i was stuck earlier. Really appreciate it...